# Simplest way to enforce that a module is only instanced once?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Suppose I have a (not synthesizable) simulation-only Verilog module.

How can I detect/enforce if it is elaborated more than once anywhere in a simulation?

```
module Singleton();
  // I only want one of these...
endmodule

module GOOD_Design();
  Singleton singleton();
endmodule

module BAD_Design();
  Singleton singleton1();
  Singleton singleton2();
endmodule
```

- My best thought is to create a static variable in a package and do something like this:

```
package SingletonPkg();
  static bit once = 1'b0;
endpackage

module Singleton();
  initial begin: singleton
    if (SingletonPkg::once == 1'b1)
      $fatal(2);
    SingletonPkg::once = 1'b1;
  end
  ...
endmodule: Singleton
```

Seems a lot of work (and I still have to make the test/set into an atomic operation).
I could use the same approach with a DPI function as well, and keep the bit in C instead of SV.

Nevertheless, is there a better/simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it slightly simpler by using a class

```
package SingletonPkg;
 class C;
  static bit once = 1'b0;
  function new;
     if (once++ != 0) $fatal(2);
  endfunction
 endclass
endpackage

module Singleton();
  SingletonPkg::C = new; 
  ...
endmodule: Singleton
```

Comment: Thanks @dave_59.  For extra credit, how would you do this if it needed to work on Verilator (which doesn't support packages or classes) as well?

Answer (score 2):

and without classes

```
int  count = 0;
module Singleton();
  initial begin
      if (count != 0) 
        $error("Multiple instances of %m");
      count ++;
    end
endmodule

module BAD_Design();
  Singleton singleton1();
  Singleton singleton2();
endmodule
```

Comment: I feel like there's a race for all of these. What if *after* singleton1's initial block reads the value of 'count', but before it can increment, that singleton2 performs its test...

Comment: there is no race in verilog simulation here. In general procedural blocks, like always, or initial, must be executed as whole without interruption. The only allowed preemption points are different delay statements, which do not exist here. There are no real parallel threads in verilog simulation.

Comment: @Serge not really true since many tools are attempting to execute on multiple cores.

Comment: @dave_59 i did not want to overcomplicate my answer. Yes, they can involve real threads, but they should take care of side effects and guarantee determinism in cases like that (4.5). So, in *general* the behavior is supposed to be similar to a single-threaded flow.